# XML+PHP+DOM "write on xml" Why it's not working in a specific server?

Tags: php, xml

I just can't figure why it's not working on my server...

I hope someone will help me please :( I will try to make it as clear as possible..

I have made a good working script in PHP+XML+DOM that write into xml and display it with an xml reader. and it's working good on some free hosting

now..I copy the files into my server and it's not working.
I can see the xml with the reader.. but i can't write on the xml file.

**Those are the very same files in both places..**

**Can you help me please?**

**BTW:Feel free to add any data to the xml..it's only for the example..**

**Sites:**

Free Hosting:  http://ofear.onlinewebshop.net/xml/XmlReader.php

My Server: `http://apps.sce.ac.il/testxml/asce/xml/XmlReader.php`

**PhpInfo:**

Free Hosting: `http://ofear.onlinewebshop.net/xml/phpinfo.php`

My Server: `http://apps.sce.ac.il/testxml/asce/xml/phpinfo.php`

**Files:**

**events.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<events>
    <record>
        <event>1</event>
        <eventDate>2</eventDate>
        <desc>3</desc>
    </record>
</events>
```

**parser.php:**  *(I added echos for debugging)*

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
echo("set header<br/>");

$record = array(
 'event' => $_POST['event'],
    'eventDate' => $_POST['eventDate'],
    'desc' => $_POST['desc'],
);
echo("set array<br/>");

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'events.xml' );
echo("make new dom and load the xml<br/>");

$doc->formatOutput = true;
echo("formatin output<br/>");

$r = $doc->getElementsByTagName("events")->item(0);
echo("get element events<br/>");

$b = $doc->createElement("record");
echo("create element record<br/>");

$event = $doc->createElement("event");
echo("create element event<br/>");

$event->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["event"] )
);
echo("create TextNode event<br/>");

$b->appendChild( $event );
echo("appendChild event<br/>");

$eventDate = $doc->createElement("eventDate");
$eventDate->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["eventDate"] )
);
echo("create TextNode eventDate<br/>");

$b->appendChild( $eventDate );
echo("appendChild eventDate<br/>");

$desc = $doc->createElement("desc");
$desc->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $record["desc"] )
);
echo("create TextNode desc<br/>");

$b->appendChild( $desc );
echo("appendChild desc<br/>");

$r->insertBefore( $b,$r->firstChild );
echo("insertBefore firstChild<br/>");

$doc->save("events.xml");
echo("Saving events.xml<br/>");

echo("<br/><br/><a href='XmlReader.php'>Go Back to XML Reader</a><br/>");
   // header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");    
?>
```

**XmlReader.php:**   *(only the php script)*

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'events.xml' );

$events = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "record" );
foreach( $events as $record )
{
  $events = $record->getElementsByTagName( "event" );
  $event = $events->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $eventDates= $record->getElementsByTagName( "eventDate" );
  $eventDate= $eventDates->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $descs = $record->getElementsByTagName( "desc" );
  $desc = $descs->item(0)->nodeValue;

  echo "<tr><td>$event</td><td>$eventDate</td><td>$desc</td></tr>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: why nobody help me :( where are everyone?

Comment: How do you verify that it's not working? What errors do you get? What's printed by parser.php?

Comment: that's the problem.. I know that it's not working becuse no data is added to the xml(see XmlReader.php) and there is no error.. that what wierd in it.. It's like the server knows what DOM is but he don't do any of the following functions..

Comment: Please add `error_reporting(E_ALL), ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of parser.php, run the script and post the output.

Comment: not another problem on file permission?

Comment: I add the script. not a singel error... hehe and no.. i gave a 755 premission to all files..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the file permission.

I gave a 755 permission to all files and it resolved it.

Thanks to [rik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656039/xmlphpdom-write-on-xml-why-its-not-working-in-a-specific-server?noredirect=1#comment5129447_4656039) with his suggestion.

> Please add error_reporting(E_ALL), ini_set('display_errors', 1); on top of parser.php, run the script and post the output.